# how to resolve a type safe collection in the constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have this object structure

```
public interface IHandler<in TMessage>
{
    void HandleMessage(TMessage messageType);
}

public class MessageType1
{
}

public class MessageType2
{
}

public class HandlerMessageType1 : IHandler<MessageType1>
{
    public void HandleMessage(T messageType)
    {
    }
}

public class HandlerMessageType2 : IHandler<MessageType2>
{
    public void HandleMessage(T messageType)
    {
    }
}
```

and the registration

```
container.Collection.Register(typeof(IHandler<>), new[]
        {
            typeof(HandlerMessageType1),
            typeof(HandlerMessageType2)
        });
```

how the constructor of the class where this is injected should look like?

```
  public class ClientClass
  {
     public ClientClass(IEnumerable<IHandler<>> handlers)
     {
     }
  }
```

like this doesn't work... how the signature of the client class constructor should look like?

this was edited to improve the example.

tkx in advance

Paulo Aboim Pinto

Comment: Too broad and its really unclear on what you are trying to do. However my guess is its something like `public ctr(Handler2 Handler)` or  `public ctr(IHandler<Handler2> Handler)`  though i must admit i am completely confused

Comment: I agree with Saruman. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. What's the function of letting the handler refer to itself, which is really weird. Please explain why this is, and why you need all handlers injected. Note that this problem doesn't seem DI related. Wjhat you are trying to do isn't valid C#. You need to change your design, but without additional details, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: Sorry if the example is not good enough .. .I improve it. The idea is have not a IHandler injection but a types class IHandler<T>

Comment: Your edit still isn't valid c#. Is does not compile. At least create an example that we can compile and explain what it is you want to do when the  IEnumerable<IHandler<T>> is injected.

Comment: that is what I want to know ... how can I make it work!

Comment: that is what I want to know ... how can I make it work!
right now my client class has as parameter the IEnumerable<IHandler> and I want to replace with something that will return a list like the registration IEnumerable<IHandler<>>

Comment: our actual implementation is not standard. 
in the registration we do what is in this file
https://github.com/aboimpinto/neo-sharp/blob/development/src/NeoSharp.Core/DI/Modules/NetworkModule.cs

Comment: and the MessageHandlerProxy, where the list is injected it's here
https://github.com/aboimpinto/neo-sharp/blob/development/src/NeoSharp.Core/Messaging/MessageHandlerProxy.cs

Comment: this implementation and everything but elegant and very complicated to follow. I'm working on this solution 
Registration: https://github.com/aboimpinto/neo-sharp/blob/SyncNodeBranch/src/NeoSharp.Core/DI/Modules/NetworkModule.cs
Usage: https://github.com/aboimpinto/neo-sharp/blob/SyncNodeBranch/src/NeoSharp.Core/Messaging/MessageHandlerProxy.cs

Comment: the actual implementation is similar of the example provided, but we would like to keep the type safe Message Handlers.. this is what we want to do

Comment: Please provide the code for `ClientClass` and describe and demonstrate what you want to do inside `ClientClass` with that collection of handlers.

Comment: this is to implement the Strategy Pattern where I receive a list of strategies and in the Client class I will iterate in all and choose the right strategy

Comment: Please update your question to show this implementation in code.

Answer (score 0):

I Know if I understood, but with unity you can have:

```
public class Handler1 : IHandler
{
    public void HandlerType()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Handler1");
   }
}

public class Handler2 : IHandler
    {
        public void HandlerType()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Handler2");
        }
    }

public interface IHandler
    {
        void HandlerType();
    }
```

Unity configuration

```
public static class DependencyConfiguration

{
    public static UnityContainer Config()
    {
        var unity = new UnityContainer();
        unity.RegisterType<IHandler, Handler1>("Handler1");
        unity.RegisterType<IHandler, Handler2>("Handler2");
        unity.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IHandler>>();


        return unity;
    }
}
```

A class to resolve:

```
public class ListOfTypes
    {
        private List<IHandler> handlers;
        public ListOfTypes(IEnumerable<IHandler> handlers)
        {
            this.handlers = handlers.ToList();
        }

        public void PrintHandlers()
        {
            handlers.ForEach(_ => _.HandlerType());
        }

    }
```

The program:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Resolve sample");
            var unity = DependencyConfiguration.Config();
            var lstOfTypes = unity.Resolve<ListOfTypes>();

            lstOfTypes.PrintHandlers();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: tkx for the example and this is what I already have, a list of IHandler been injected in the constructor of my class.
This IHander is not type safe and what I want is to have a list to type safe IHandlers<T>

maybe the example is not the best I will redo it.